# How do I compile this recursive function in Julia?

Tags: julia, tail-recursion

The following line of code is a recursive helper function for generating the nth Fibonacci number. From Julia's REPL `include("filename.jl")`. It's the only line of code in the file and it won't compile. Julia ver. 4.5 and 5.1. Have tried using bracketing parentheses and also have rewritten in standard if-else format, all to no avail. This code will simply not compile for me. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
helper(current, next, n) = n==0 ? current : helper(next, current+next, n-1)
```

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting?

Comment: Alexander -- No error msg on the include("filename.jl") command, but when attempt to use helper, the error msg is "ERROR: UndefVarError: helper not defined"

Comment: works fine for me...

Comment: For me too: 
```julia> include("helper.jl")
helper (generic function with 1 method)

julia> helper(1,1,8)
34
``` Why do you think it is an issue with compilation?

Comment: Alexander -- Yes, apparently works fine for others too. Copied it from a website. I've installed a stable package of Julia on four Ubuntu systems (ver 4.5) and one OS X system (ver 5.1) and the line won't compile on any of them. It's a mystery. Thank you.

Comment: Michael -- Well, others are able to compile this simple function, everything else I have used has compiled okay (once I got the code right), but with this particular function, the include command doesn't respond with "helper (generic function with 1 method)" (that's clue #1), and when I attempt to use helper, I get the error msg quoted above (clue #2). Those are my reasons for concluding that it hasn't compiled. Thank you.

Comment: I *think* by compiled you mean defined? But anyway, this seems weird. Sorry if this is an annoying question but are you sure that the file you are including has that exact text in it? Also does defining it on the REPL work?

Comment: Does `readstring("filename.jl")` return what you think it should?

Comment: Alexander -- I'm annoyed by my, so far, inability to solve this problem, not by questions intended to help me understand what's going on. I appreciate your willingness to be involved in this. Exact text, yes. I hadn't thought of typing the function directly into the REPL and will try that now. Thanks.

Comment: Matt -- I'll try that now also.

Comment: Alexander -- When I type the one line of code directly into REPL, I get the response `helper (generic function with 1 method)`, and when I then type `helper(0, 1, 10)` I get the expected response of `55`.

Comment: Matt -- When I type `readstring("filename.jl")` into the REPL I get the following error msg `ERROR UndefVarError: readstring not defined`. It appears there's a Package I don't have installed, though don't know which one. I did this in Ubuntu and Julia ver 4.5.

Comment: So I can enter the function by hand directly into REPL and get correct results, but unable to get correct results when entering via the `include` command. And, so far at least, only with respect to this specific line of code.  `include` has worked with everything else once I eliminated my errors.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me find a way to define that helper function, so that it can be used. Thank you very much.

Comment: Oh, sorry, readstring is the new name for this function in Julia 0.5.  Try `readall("filename.jl")`. The point is that I don't think you're loading the file you think you're loading.

Comment: Matt -- `readall("filename.jl")` works with Julia ver 4.5 and `readstring("filename.jl")` works with Julia ver 5.1. Just tried them both. Thanks. By "works" I mean that each prints out the one-line file contents.

Comment: And now, miracle of miracles, each of these systems is now able to read, compile, define `helper()` simply by starting Julia's REPL in a fresh terminal, and executing `include("filename.jl")`. It was like training a dog to do a new trick. Can't explain why, but it's consistent now. Perhaps there was something "funny" about earlier versions of my file. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Matt -- Yesterday you remarked "The point is that I don't think you're loading the file you think you're loading." I meant to follow up on that observation but forgot to do so. If you mean that I was connected to a wrong directory, that isn't the problem. What did you mean? I was using the include() command in REPL to access the file. How would that pull up something else? How can that happen? Thanks.

Comment: I've now installed IJulia/notebook() in these systems and it seems easier to use than the REPL.

Comment: Alexander -- I was using "compiled" in a layman's sense, meaning the entire process of converting source code to executable code. Yes, the process went part way and didn't provide a defined object. Thanks for pointing out that distinction.